# Starting a Text to Speech in your Language

Tags: text-to-speech

Is there any opensource library that I could use to feed the letters and sounds and produce a text to speech system.

What must I do to start from scratch? Python would be my language of choice so where must I be headed to develop my own text to speech in my language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a list of a few Open Source TTS engines:

- [MBrola](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html)
- [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php)
- [Festival Speech Synthesis](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)
- [FLite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/)
- [Festvox](http://festvox.org/)
- [GnuSpeech](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuspeech/)
- [Epos Speech](http://epos.ure.cas.cz/)

Maybe one of the covers what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Bjoern, I m exploring Flite for TTS, was wondering if I can add support for languages other than English. Have you done anything regarding this or have any idea? BTW +1 for your answer.

Comment: Its been a while since I've been working with TTS, the last time in C++ and VB6 about 10 years ago. I've not checked deeply into this topic since and only marginally looked into the engines provided above (aka "do they work!? yes!"), so unfortunately I can't help you with that very much.

Comment: I'm using Flite for android.  Do you know if Festival can be implemented on android?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the possibilities on android.